# load wordpress related post one by one using ajax when page scroll

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I would like to be load or add related post using ajax when page scroll in single post page. But I'm getting Ajax status 404. Can somebody help me out?

functions file :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_zi', 'related_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_zi', 'related_posts');

function related_posts() {

  $post_tag = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

  //$paged = $_POST['page'];

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    /*'paged' => $paged,*/
    'caller_get_posts'=>1,
    'tax_query'=> array(
      array(
       'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
       'field'    => 'term_id',
       'terms'    => $post_tag
      )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
  );

  $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
    ?>
    <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
      <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
      <?php the_excerpt() ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php
  endif;

  die();
}
```

single.php

```
    <main id="main" class="site-main " role="main">
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'single' ); ?>

       <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
    <div class="above-comment">
    <?php get_template_part('widget-templates/above-comment', 'widget') ;?>
     </div>
    <?php
   // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template

   if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
       comments_template();
   endif;

   ?>
   <div class="loadMorePosts">loadmore</div>
```

js/jquery file

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - 

    $(window).height()) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        action: 'load_posts_by_zi'
                    },
                    complete: function(loadMorePosts) {
                        $container.append(loadMorePosts);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

I would like to be able to update the URL as well but am unsure how I can go about adding that. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: getting Ajax status 404 . post not showing

Comment: caller_get_posts is deprecated, use ignore_sticky_posts instead.